# 1 text input that sources 2 lists

Tags: usability

I have a widget which is composed of 1 text input, and 2 lists below it. By clicking the list title, "List 1" or "List 2", the user sets which list gets populated when they press enter.

[image: List 1 is active]

List 1 is the active list, meaning if the user presses Enter, List 1 will receive a new list item with the value of the input.

[image]

Here, List 2 is the active list.

To me, it's not obvious at first glance that this behavior exists. I did set `cursor: pointer` on each title, but the user has to actually mouse over them to see that.
It just looks like one title has a background color and the other doesn't. How can I make the functionality more apparent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Allow users to select the List first** in the same element before they type and hit enter. Keep the mostly used category (based on research) as default: **It appears as well organized and efficient approach**.

[image]

---

It's similar to what [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/) does:

[image]

Comment: Good option too, although Amazon one is meant for search. I feel the input from the question looks like a search field rather than a text input to add elements.

Comment: @Alvaro Yes, the question had confused me too. It seems the OP wants to search for items available in selected list.

Comment: I like this answer, thanks. My input is an autocomplete/search. When they select an option, it gets added to the "active" list.

Answer (score 3):

give the input field directly in the list so that user can enter the value directly by clicking. and it is easily understandable at first look.

[image]

Comment: Exactly. Specially considering there is more than enough space for two inputs.